# syscall number for crypt?

Tags: ruby, system-calls, crypt

I'm trying to call the `crypt` system call from Ruby. Ruby has a `Kernel#syscall` method (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-syscall), but it needs the number of the system call, not the name. I have found many lists of system call numbers, but none of them include `crypt`.

Any ideas how I call it?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to tell us your OS/kernel and architecture. Anyway neither Linux nor *BSD has such a syscall.

Comment: Are you by chance referencing the posix libc function `crypt`? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html

Comment: You need to look up the syscall numbers for the specific version of the specific kernel of the specific operating system you are using. Since you do not tell us what those are, we cannot help you. Note, however, that I do not know of any well-known kernel which has a `crypt` syscall.

Comment: @photoionized Yes, I guess I am. Not being a C programmer I obviously don't get the difference between a syscall and a library function... is it not possible to call `crypt` in the same way as a syscall?